# How to Disable Pre-population of Password on Password Reset

Tags: password, wp-login-form, reset

because of the way my site template works, I need to stop WordPress from pre-populating a new password when a user is brought back to the site, after clicking on the password reset link in the email they get.

I just want them to be taken to the password reset page, have the password field be blank, and type in their own password.

I've tried putting this in functions.php, but it doesn't work:

```
function disable_autofill_password_reset( $args, $user ) {
    $args['autocomplete'] = 'off';
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'rp_generate_password_form_args', 'disable_autofill_password_reset', 10, 2 );
```

Can anyone point me in the right  direction?

[image]

Comment: I was just wondering, have you found a different answer to your question, and if so, what was it? Or did you end up with a different approach, or maybe you decided to keep the password pre-population?

Comment: I use the Buddyboss template, and they finally admitted that the "Retype new password" field is a bug. It shouldn't even be there. The default WordPress behavior is to prepopulate the pw, but not ask the user to retype it.

Comment: Yes, it's actually indeed a default behavior and shouldn't need to be worried of, hence I deleted my answer. However, you should [write your own answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), because it might help someone else. :) Cheers!